# ProcessBuilder won't properly run with unified arguments with spaces in a path

Tags: java, groovy, processbuilder

I am trying to pass ProcessBuilder several arguments which require tags at the beginning for parameters (-).  My command-line command looks something like this, and runs just fine when run in cmd.

```
msdeploy.exe -verb:sync -source:contentPath='\My\Folder with Space\Path' -dest:auto
```

My project uses a groovy script and implements ProcessBuilder to run the command.  ProcessBuilder sees the folder path as having spaces, and therefore, by working as intended, places the arg3 in quotations.

ProcessBuilder is passed the arguments:

```
arg1 = msdeploy.exe
arg2 = -verb:sync
arg3 = -source:contentPath='C:\My\Folder with Space\Path'
arg4 = -dest:auto
```

ProcessBuilder interprets and runs the command as:

```
msdeploy.exe -verb:sync "-source:contentPath='C:\My\Folder with Space\Path'" -dest:auto
```

The following error is returned:

```
Error: Unrecognized argument '"-source:contentPath=C:\Program Files\udeploy\agent"'. All arguments must begin with "-".
```

Escaping characters does not fix this issue, because it still recognizes the spaces even if they're escaped and adds quotations around the entire -source argument.  The dash (-) must come first in an msdeploy argument.

I need to know how it is possible to run unified arguments like this with spaces in ProcessBuilder that have tags at the beginning, such as the '-'.

Comment: What is the exact java command you are using for ProcessBuilder? Are you passing values as multiple commands, or as a single String?

Comment: msdeploy.exe.  Values are being passed as a String list array.

Comment: What is the exact java command you are using for ProcessBuilder?

Comment: Try using something like -source:contentPath=\"C:\\My\\Folder with Space\\Path\"" as the parameter. Make sure you are using a String array and separating each parameter into its own element

Comment: The windows tool probably does not like  / in the arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to get ProcessBuilder to work with this command.  I did get my intended result, however, by simply building the command string manually and passing it directly to Runtime().exec as shown:

```
def command = "msdeploy.exe -verb:sync -source:contentPath='\My\Folder with Space\Path' -dest:auto"
def proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command)
proc.waitForProcessOutput(System.out, System.err)
if (proc.exitValue()) {
    throw new Exception("Command failed with exit code: " + proc.exitValue())
}
return proc.exitValue()
```

Answer (score 0):

My CLI is [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) when I'm obliged to work in Windows, in part because of problems like this. The equivalent command would be:

```
msdeploy.exe -verb:sync -source:contentPath="/cygdrive/c/My/Folder\ with\ Space/Path"
```

The file separator is a forward slash and the spaces must be escaped with a backslash. Takes the guess work out.